# D3 live pie chart not updating?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am relatively new to Javascript programming so I apologize for any noobiness.

I am trying to have a pie chart update with the data from a csv in real time but having an issue with the chart updating.

The data is coming from a registration form and I want to count the number of instances of a certain field. I prepare the data in my script as follows:

```
    function loadData(){
        d3.csv("/data.csv",function(data){
            temparr=[];
            count = data.length;
            var positions={};
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                if(!positions[d.POSITION])
                {
                    positions[d.POSITION] = 1;
                }
                else 
                {
                    positions[d.POSITION] = positions[d.POSITION] + 1;
                }
            });
            Object.keys(positions).forEach(function(prop){
                var tempobj={};
                tempobj["position"]=prop;
                tempobj["value"] = positions[prop];
                if(positions[prop] < min){min=positions[prop]}
                if(positions[prop] > max){max=positions[prop]}
                temparr.push(tempobj);
            });
            barData=temparr;
});
}
```

The chart I am updating is created by appending to an SVG element in my body:

```
            var g=chart.append("g").attr("transform","translate("+width/2+","+height/2+")");

            arc = g.selectAll(".arc");

            var temp = arc.data(pie(barData))
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class","arc");

            temp.append("path")
            .attr("d",path)
            .attr("fill",function(d){return color(d.data.position);});
```

Then I update it using:

```
        arc.data(pie(barData));

        var temp = arc.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class","arc");

        arc.exit().remove();

        temp.append("path")
        .attr("d",path)
        .attr("fill",function(d){return color(d.data.position);});
```

But after I change the data, nothing happens. Could anyone enlighten me as to what I'm missing? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The function `enter()` returns only the new items that are entering the selection. But the second time around, you have no new items entering - you are just updating existing data. So the result of `enter()`, which is being assigned to the variable `temp`, is empty, and none of the existing items get their `d` or `fill` changed.

If you change the final few lines of your update code to select all arcs first, both existing and new, like below, it should (I hope) update the paths and colours:

```
g.selectAll(".arc path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("fill",function(d){return color(d.data.position);});
```

Comment: So I made g global (previously arc was from my testing). Should I run selectAll(".arc") again then enter that, do the path and text stuff, then use your code snippet? Also, I potentially do have new data if a unique position is entered.

Comment: If your second data reload adds or removes new data points then yes you should run the enter() and exit() lines again to add and remove SVG elements, yes. Then run my update code on a fresh selectAll to catch everything

Comment: Okay, so I selectAll(".arc"), bind the new data, run exit().remove() to remove outgoing data, then run a fresh selectAll to update the current elements. This works now and the chart updates with new positions, but removing a slice leaves a hole.